# Overloading virtual generic method

Tags: c#, generics

I'd like to ask if someone can help me.

I have base generic class

```
public class Base<T> where T : new()
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual string Foo()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("");
    }
}
```

Then I have

```
public class A : Base<A>
{
    public override string Foo()
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

and in my main code I would like to do something like:

```
A entity = new A();
var x = entity.Foo();

List<A> entityList = new List<A>();  
var y = entityList.Foo();
```

my code works for entity and x, but I'd like to overload Foo to be called also on a list. Can someone help?

Comment: You need loop thru the list and call Foo for each of the item in the list.

Comment: But that doesn't make any sense. Why you want to be able to call method defined on single instance, on list of such instances? What should it even return?

Comment: Well, in the first case I want to return Dictionary<string, object> of properties with values and in the second case want to return List<Dictionary<string, object>>... Does it make any sense?

Comment: You can create an extension method Foo for List<A> which will return the List of Dictionary, but inside the method you will have to do the same thing which I explained in the earlier comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such things (when you need to extend existing class without modifying source code of it) you can create [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods), for example

```
public static class BaseExtensions
{
    public static string Foo<T>(this IEnumerable<Base<T>> items) where T : new()
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            builder.Append(item.Foo());
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

that concatenates all *Foo* results of items in array/list.